# Javascript eval() function not working properly

Tags: javascript, eval, evaluate

I'm currently making a calculator with HTML, CSS and Javascript, for practice. I found out that the "built in" eval function did the math from a string. But it doesn't work properly.

I don't know what the problem is. But when i for example do: 11+11/2 which should be 11. Becomes 16.5 for some reason. I have no idea why. I would really appreciate some help.

Here is the code:

```
    function revealAnswer(){
            var math = document.getElementById("numbersInputted");
            math.innerHTML += " = " + eval(math.innerHTML);

    }
```

Comment: Why should `11+11/2` be `11`? `11/2` is `5.5`, and `11 + 5.5` is `16.5`.

Comment: Try `(11 + 11)/2` and think back to when you learned about operator precedence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about PEDMAS not programming

Comment: Asking about `eval` is a red herring -- the question is the same as asking about the behavior of `math.innerHTML += " = " + (11+11/2)` or even just `console.log(11+11/2)`.

Comment: @Paulpro It's about more than programming as it centers around the use of `eval()` as well.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I disagree. The eval is working properly.

Comment: @Paulpro I didn't say that it wasn't. The question, though, brings `eval()` and it's use into play. Look at the title of the post.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I did read the title. It says `eval` isn't working properly, which is completely misconstrued. t's working fine.

Comment: @Paulpro Thus, a misunderstanding of what the code is doing.... Anyway, I disagree with the closing of the question.

Comment: I should'v added that i don't really know what eval is a 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of reasons why this is the wrong approach.

First, `innerHTML` returns a string containing, not only the text content of an element, but also any nested HTML elements as well. If it's just the text you want, use `textContent`.

Next, by having the user input the actual math operator they want to use in the same string with the numbers creates more confusion.  Have the user enter that separately and then you can use `if/then` logic to ultimately use the correct operator.

Next (and this is the important part), don't ever use `eval()`. It is not required to solve just about any problem you could encounter, but it opens up the door to "Cross Site Scripting" attacks on your website. Additionally, it manipulates the `this` binding and executes its code in its own scope.

What you really need to do is simply convert the string input into a number so that you can do math with it. You can do this with **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** and **[`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)**

So, your line could be:

```
math.innerHTML += " = " + parseFloat(math.textContent);
```

Lastly, for math, the order of operations is:

- Parenthesis
- Exponents
- Multiplication
- Division
- Addtion
- Subtraction

You can see that division is done prior to addition and that means that in your expression: `11 + 11/2`, first `11/2` is evaluated (5.5) and then it is added to `11` (16.5).

Finally, remember that the `+` operator in JavaScript can mean mathematical addition or string concatenation and if one of the operands is a string, the other will be converted to a string.

Comment: Ok. I think i get it now. Thanks for spending some of your time to learn me! :)